# jQuery AJAX assigning success data to an element's value

Tags: jquery, ajax

How do you properly do this?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "something",
    success: function(data) {
        //let data.name = "Bob"
        div.append("<input value='data.name'>");
    }
});
```

The markup becomes

```
<input value='data.name'>
```

I want it to become

```
<input value='Bob'>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to break out of the string and concatenate the variable into the string;

```
$.ajax({
    url: "something",
    success: function(data) {
        //let data.name = "Bob"
        div.append("<input value='" + data.name + "'>");
    }
});
```